# @: vs <text></text> in displaying content for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

which is a better way in displaying content in asp.net mvc.

Using `@:` or `<text></text>`

It seems that i cannot find the pros and cons of these

Comment: You can use `<text>` inside code blocks marked with `@`. Useful when defining item templates in grid, list helpers

Answer (score 4):

`@:` can be viewed as a shortcut for single-line `<text></text>`. In other words, these two lines work exactly the same:

```
@:single line content
<text>single line content</text>
```

However note that `text` also gives you an opportunity to output multi-line content, and `@:` does not:

```
<text>Can't do that
with @:, just with text
</text>
```

You can find more details in this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax).

Comment: We can use multiple `@:` sequences to output multi-line content using `@:`. check [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax).